# Delete a selected QGraphicsPixmapItem in a scene

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a sort of image viewer in which I put a background image ("Affichage du mur" button) and then I load images with the "Importer l'oeuvre" button (you can load as many images you want). It works fine but I would like that we could delete the images ... in fact I would like the image that we delete is the image selected by the user. I can't get the selected image to be deleted with the "Suppression de l'oeuvre" button ... **it seems that there is a selectedItems() method but I don't know how to use it in my code.** Can you help me please ? Here is a very simplified code of what I am doing :

```
import os, sys

try : import Image
except ImportError : from PIL import Image

# Imports PyQt5 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QGridLayout, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, \
                            QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsItem, QApplication, \
                            QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QColor, QTransform
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


class TEST(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TEST, self).__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle('TEST')
        
        self.setGeometry(10, 20, 1280, 760)
        self.setMinimumSize(1280, 760)

        # ----------------------------------------
        self.graphe_vue = MonGraphiqueVueMur()
        # ----------------------------------------
        
        bout_visio_mur = QPushButton("Affichage du mur")
        bout_visio_mur.setMaximumWidth(230)
        bout_visio_mur.setMinimumWidth(230)
        
        bout_visio_oeuvre = QPushButton("Importer l'oeuvre")
        bout_visio_oeuvre.setMaximumWidth(230)
        bout_visio_oeuvre.setMinimumWidth(230)
        
        bout_supprimer_oeuvre = QPushButton("Suppression de l'oeuvre")
        bout_supprimer_oeuvre.setMaximumWidth(230)
        bout_supprimer_oeuvre.setMinimumWidth(230)
        
        # ------------------------------------------------------------
        bout_visio_mur.clicked.connect(self.graphe_vue.afficher_mur)
        bout_visio_oeuvre.clicked.connect(self.graphe_vue.afficher_image_oeuvre)
        bout_supprimer_oeuvre.clicked.connect(self.graphe_vue.supprimer_image_oeuvre)
        # ------------------------------------------------------------

        grid = QGridLayout()

        grid.addWidget(self.graphe_vue, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(bout_visio_mur, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(bout_visio_oeuvre, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(bout_supprimer_oeuvre, 3, 0)
        
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(grid)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        
class MaScene(QGraphicsScene) :
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None) :
        super(MaScene, self).__init__(parent)
        
        
class MonGraphiquePixmapItemMur(QGraphicsPixmapItem) :
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MonGraphiquePixmapItemMur, self).__init__(parent)
        
        
class MonGraphiquePixmapItemOeuvre(QGraphicsPixmapItem) :
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MonGraphiquePixmapItemOeuvre, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True) 

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        print('setAcceptHoverEvents --> Position', event.pos(), type(event.pos()), type(event.pos().x()), type(event.pos().x()))
        print("Position X", event.pos().x(), "Position Y", event.pos().y())
        
        
class MonGraphiqueVueMur(QGraphicsView) :

    backgroundcolor = QColor(100, 100, 100)
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None) :
        super(MonGraphiqueVueMur, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setBackgroundBrush(self.backgroundcolor)

        self.scene  = MaScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)


    def wheelEvent(self, event):

        zoomInFactor = 1.1
        zoomOutFactor = 1 / zoomInFactor
        
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)

        oldPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
    
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            zoomFactor = zoomInFactor
        else:
            zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor
        self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)
    
        newPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
    
        delta = newPos - oldPos
        self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())
        
        
    def afficher_mur(self) :
        
        ouv = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Ouvrir une image', os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Images (*.jpg *.jpeg *.JPG *.JPEG *.png *.gif)')[0]
        chemin_fichier = str(ouv)
        
        img_mur = Image.open(chemin_fichier)

        self.scene.clear()
        self.items().clear()

        largeur, hauteur = img_mur.size

        pixmap = QPixmap(chemin_fichier)

        item = MonGraphiquePixmapItemMur(pixmap)

        item.setTransformationMode(Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        self.scene.addItem(item)

        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.fitInView(item, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        x, y = 0, 0
        self.setSceneRect(-x, -y, largeur, hauteur)
        self.centerOn(10, 10)

        self.show()


    def afficher_image_oeuvre(self) :
        
        ouv = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Ouvrir une image', os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Images (*.jpg *.jpeg *.JPG *.JPEG *.png *.gif)')[0]
        chemin_fichier = str(ouv)

        pixmap = QPixmap(chemin_fichier)
        
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(700, 700, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        item = MonGraphiquePixmapItemOeuvre(pixmap)
        
        item.setTransformationMode(Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)

        self.scene.addItem(item)

        self.setScene(self.scene)
        
        ###################################################################################
        iteme = self.scene.selectedItems()
        print("iteme", iteme) # Return []
        ###################################################################################

        self.show()

 
    def supprimer_image_oeuvre(self) :
        
        import sip
        
        tous_items = list(self.scene.items())
        print("len(tous_items)", len(tous_items))
        print("tous_items", tous_items)

        for i in tous_items :
            if str(type(i)) != "<class '__main__.MonGraphiquePixmapItemMur'>" :
                self.scene.removeItem(tous_items[0])
                sip.delete(tous_items[0])

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TEST()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance.

I'd have other questions to ask but we'll see that later.

Comment: Please avoid using foreign language for functions, it makes reading your code more difficult. Also, you should not use capitalized names for functions, I suggest you to read the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to cycle through `selectedItems()`, there's absolutely no need to use the `sip` module, nor check the class using the string (which is *not* a good way to do so).

```
def supprimer_image_oeuvre(self) :
    for item in self.scene.selectedItems():
        self.scene.removeItem(item)
```

Comment: Sorry, it was simple very simple. Another question, the last loaded image always appears in the foreground in the view. Is it possible to make the selected image appear in front of others ?

Comment: You can use [`item.setZValue()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setZValue) to set absolute z values or [`item.stackBefore(other)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#stackBefore) to change the order of colliding items on the same z-level. I strongly suggest you to carefully and patiently study the whole graphics view framework documentation about the QGraphicsView, the QGraphicsScene and the basic QGraphicsItem classes, as they are as powerful as complex and thoroughly implemented.